# Insert values from text boxes to database in Visual C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginPageBindingSource.EndEdit();

        int pcode = 0;
        pcode = int.Parse(pincode.Text);
        personalbalancesheet.BalanceSheetDataSet1TableAdapters.LoginPageTableAdapter myadapter = new personalbalancesheet.BalanceSheetDataSet1TableAdapters.LoginPageTableAdapter();
        try
        {
            myadapter.Insert(name.Text, loginname.Text, password.Text, add1.Text, add2.Text, phoneno.Text, city.Text, statebox.Text, pcode);
            MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("inserion failed");
        }
    }
```

**Edit: Adding more details from comments**

The above code is not working , as I am trying to save the values from text boxes to database... Tthere are no compile or runtime errors but the database does not get updated. Output shown is "data inserted".

The code is this much only. `Insert()` is a library method. Can you provide me with any alternative code for the data insertion in database?

Comment: Please stop shouting. And please ask a question.

Comment: You say it's not working but you don't tell us what isn't working. I presume your catch block is getting called? What exception is being thrown? Does it not show the error message but nothing is getting added to the database? Help us to help you.

Comment: i m sorry . the above code is not working , as i am trying to save the values from text boxes to database .. there is no compile and runtime errors but the database doesnot get updated. output shown is "data inserted".

Comment: Then you're not showing the correct code. How does the adapter work? Are the connection string settings correct? Have you tried -debugging-?

Comment: What's the code for myadapter.Insert? Is it your own code, or a library method?

Comment: the code is this much only. insert is a library method. can u provide me with any alternative code for the data insertion in database ..

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity is the data mapping layer you're using hasn't committed the transaction to the database. So though your insert method appears to succeed, nothing would have changed in the actual database.

**EDIT:**

Assuming you're using a [TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as your variable name suggests, then you need to call `TableAdapter.Update()` to actually persist the data to the database. Here's a code sample from MSDN:

```
try
{
    this.Validate();
    this.customersBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.customersTableAdapter.Update(this.northwindDataSet.Customers);
    MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
}
```

[MSDN - How to: Update Data Using a TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: thank u man . but this does not solve the problem. i checked the connection it is working fine as data is being retrieved from the database but insert and update operation are not working.